# OpenCL Write back on the buffer

Tags: c++, opencl

When I try to write back on the host buffer the output of the opencl code I always get an array of zeros/nulls

Here is the kernel:

```
void kernel convolution(global const int* A, global const int* B,
        global int* C, const int size_1, const int size_2) {
    float prob_1[256];
    float prob_2[256];
    float cum_prob_1[256];
    float cum_prob_2[256];
    prob_1[get_global_id(0)] = (A[get_global_id(0)]/size_1);
    prob_2[get_global_id(0)] = (B[get_global_id(0)]/size_2);
    cum_prob_1[0] = prob_1[0];
    cum_prob_1[get_global_id(0)+1] = cum_prob_1[get_global_id(0)] + prob_1[get_global_id(0)+1];
    cum_prob_2[0] = prob_2[0];
    cum_prob_2[get_global_id(0)+1] = cum_prob_2[get_global_id(0)] + prob_2[get_global_id(0)+1];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (cum_prob_1[i] <= cum_prob_2[j]) {
            C[i] = j;
        }
        else {
            while (cum_prob_1[i] > cum_prob_2[j])
                j++;
            if (cum_prob_2[j] - cum_prob_1[i] > cum_prob_1[i] - cum_prob_2[j - 1]) {
                C[i] = j - 1;
            }
            else {
                C[i] = j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the rest of the code :

```
// create buffers on the device
cl::Buffer buffer_A(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * 256);
cl::Buffer buffer_B(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * 256);
cl::Buffer buffer_C(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * 256);

//create queue to which we will push commands for the device.
cl::CommandQueue queue(context, default_device);

//write arrays A and B to the device
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * 256, pixls_1);
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_B, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * 256, pixls_2);

//alternative way to run the kernel
cl::Kernel kernel_add = cl::Kernel(program, "convolution");
kernel_add.setArg(0, buffer_A);
kernel_add.setArg(1, buffer_B);
kernel_add.setArg(2, buffer_C);
kernel_add.setArg(3, size_1);
kernel_add.setArg(4, size_2);

queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_add, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(sizeof(cl_mem)), cl::NullRange);
queue.finish();

int lookup_table[256];
for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    lookup_table[i] = 10;
}
//read result C from the device to array C
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_C, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * 256, lookup_table);

//map the new pixel values from the lookup table
for (int i = 0; i < inp_image.total(); i++) {
    myData[i]= lookup_table[myData[i]];
}

system("pause");
return 0;
```

`lookup_table` is the one that gives me zeros/nulls but it should give me `5` in all of the cells...

Answer (score 1):

I see two things very highly suspicious to me in your code:

1. The call to `enqueueNDRangeKernel()` and notably the use of `cl::NDRange(sizeof(cl_mem))` for specifying the array of global work item dimensions... AFAICT, this just doesn't make any sense, but I might very well miss something here.
2. The use of the temporary arrays in the kernel itself: it looks to me very much like you forgot to declare them `local`. Would that be the case? And if so, you'd need to add a `barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE)` after the initialisation part.

Anyway, my feeling is that your code is meant to be used with work groups of sizes 256, with `local` memory for the temporary arrays. I might be wrong, but in any case, there are problems in the way the kernel is run, and in its logic too.